# Why foreach enters into if only on first loop?

Tags: php, loops, yii, foreach

If I loop through foreach loop only on first time it enters into if and gets variable values, so each next time it still have old values. why?

If I `print_r($i)` and kill it responds:
`A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0A0TXTTXT16`

Real amount is end of it(16). So that means it loops 16 times through loop but into if enters only on first loop of if `$type` changes. So `$type` doesn't get new value each time it runs through loop.

Code I have:

```
    $recordTypes = array('CnameRecord', 'ARecord', 'MxRecord', 'TxtRecord');
    foreach ($recordTypes as $type) {
        $modelName = $type::model()->tableName();
        $record = $type::model()->findAllbySql("SELECT * FROM $modelName WHERE vhost_id LIKE $id");
        if ($record) {
            foreach ($record as $key=>$rec) {
                if ($type == 'ARecord'){
                    $type = 'A' + $i;
                    $hostname = $rec['sub_vhost_name'];
                    $points_to = $rec['points_to'];
                    $ttl = $rec['ttl'];
                } else if ($type == 'CnameRecord') {
                    $type = 'CNAME';
                    $hostname = $rec['hostname'];
                    $points_to = $rec['points_to'];
                    $ttl = $rec['ttl'];
                } else if ($type == 'MxRecord') {
                    $type = 'MX';
                    $priority = $rec['priority'] . '    ';
                    $points_to = $rec['points_to'];
                    $ttl = $rec['ttl'];
                    $hostname = $rec['host'];
                } else if ($type == 'TxtRecord') {
                    $type = 'TXT';
                    $hostname = $rec['hostname'];
                    $points_to = '"' . $rec['txt_value'] . '"   ';
                    $ttl = $rec['ttl'];
                }
                $i++;
                print_r($type);
                $custom_content = $hostname . ' ' . $ttl . '    ' . 'IN' . '    ' . $type . '   ' . $priority . $points_to . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
print_r($i);die;
```

Comment: the iterator `$i` initialization must be outside the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using:

```
foreach ($recordTypes as $type) { ...
```

And inside the foreach you're modifying the "type" var, so in the next loops through $record, you'll fail any if statement. 
Change the $type var (inside if statements) to another var name and try again.